# How to embed a script tag into Angular component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, embed

I've got an Angular/Typescript website. I need to embed a third party script. The script generates a table.

How can I display that table inside home.component.html. Not at the start or at the beginning, within. Like so.

I've been able to get the script embedded but it doesn't look like the script is rendering so it just displays it in the source but doesn't render the table.

**Update**

The table can now rendered but only outside of app-root. It should be inside of home.component.html. [Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPNFC.png)

**home.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'

declare var myExtObject: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-careers',
  templateUrl: './careers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./careers.component.scss']
})

export class CareersComponent implements OnInit {
  private iife: any

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.iife = myExtObject()
  }

}
```

**home.component.html**

```html
<div id="BambooHR">
    <script src="https://xxxxxxx.xxx.com" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

The code behind the script is found below. I have that in an external.js file.

```js
var myExtObject = function() {

 //add css file to dom so IE8 recognizes it
 document.write('<link href="https://xxx.css" rel="stylesheet" />');

 var divId="BambooHR-ATS";
 var el=document.getElementById(divId);
 if(!el) {
  document.write("<div id=\""+divId+"\"></div>");
 }

 var xmlhttp;
 var ieFlag = 0;
 if (('XDomainRequest' in window && window.XDomainRequest !== null) && document.documentMode < 10) {
  xmlhttp=new XDomainRequest();
  ieFlag = 1;
 } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 var embedUrl = "https://xxx.php";

 var departmentId = "0";

 if (departmentId) {
  embedUrl += '?departmentId=' + encodeURIComponent(departmentId);
 }

 document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event) {
  if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
   if (ieFlag == 1) { //needed for IE9 CORS
    xmlhttp.onload = loadd;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",embedUrl);
    xmlhttp.send();

   } else {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
     if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

      var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
      var footerId="BambooHR-Footer";
      var fel=document.getElementById(footerId);

      el=document.getElementById(divId);

      if(el && !fel) {
       content += "<div id="xxx"/></a></div>";
      }

      if(el) el.innerHTML=content;
     }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET",embedUrl,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
   }
  }
 });

 function loadd() { //needed for IE9 CORS
  var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
  var footerId="BambooHR-Footer";
  var fel=document.getElementById(footerId);

  el=document.getElementById(divId);

  if(el && !fel) {
   content += "<div id=\"BambooHR-Footer\">Powered by <a href=\"http://www.bamboohr.com\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"external\"><img src=\"https://resources.bamboohr.com/images/footer-logo.png\" alt=\"BambooHR - HR software\"/></a></div>";
  }
  el.innerHTML=content;
 }
};
```

Comment: How does that script work? Do you have to call a method from it? Does it expect data to already be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't insert the script tag manually. Import the library in your `angular.json`, in `scripts` section:

```
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/yourtablelibrary/build/yourtablelibrary.min.js"
]
```

Reference: https://medium.com/@clintpitzak/how-to-use-external-javascript-libraries-in-angular-8-247baacbdccf

Answer (score 2):

All scripts are executed when the page is loaded, `<script>` tag added to dom after page is loaded does not get executed

As a result of that, embedding a script tag will not load the content of the file seams angular does not reload the page.

A solution is to make the component implement `AfterInit` interface and import the script dynamically in the `ngAfterInit` method like this

```
ngAfterInit() {
   import('./myfile.js')
  }
```

Assuming that the script to be loaded is myfile.js and is is the same directiory

Comment: Right and how would I target a div to display the content?

Comment: Be more specific, what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I'm looking to have the IIFE inside external.js shown above, instantiated on AfterInit and have the table generated displayed in my Angular component in a given div. I am able to have the table generated and displayed but only outside of <app-root> even though it's been instantiated inside  home.component.ts ngAfterInit(). Thanks for your help.