# How to add a script in angular component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to embed a Class maker test in to my angular website.

Here the script tag i got from Class maker

```
<script src="https://www.classmarker.com/public/js/embed-classmarker-1.0.0.js?quiz=4p365d69cbe3a608" data-quiz="4p365d69cbe3a608" data-width="700" data-height="800" ></script>
```

i paste it in html but it didn't work. Then i try to append this using a function by calling it in ngOnInit.

[image: my function]
**output**

when i append it to document.body it loads the exam on my website

but when i try to append the script like this

this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, script);

throws me unauthorized error. when i check the network tab, I can see below error message

[image: error message]

Can you please help me with this ?

I tried to append the script in to my component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to embed a script tag into Angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094991/how-to-embed-a-script-tag-into-angular-component)

Comment: No Sir that's not what i want. I'm about to generate more quizes for my website. i want to generate it based on the quiz number as an example. quiz=4p365d69cbe3a608.

i want to embed this inside my component. I can't declare js files inside the project.

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)? Please edit your question to include the text

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for inserting script tag in component:

```
import { Renderer2, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

class TestComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
    private renderer2: Renderer2, 
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: Document
) { }

public ngOnInit() {

    let script = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
    script.type = `application/ld+json`;
    script.text = `
        {
            "@context": "https://test.org"
            /* your test.org microdata goes here */
        }
    `;

    this.renderer2.appendChild(this.doc.body, script);
}
```

}`

Answer (score -1):

```
 initBeaconScript() {
    // Add the Beacon script dynamically after the view has been initialized
    this.beaconScript = document.createElement('script');
    this.beaconScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    this.beaconScript.text = `
        !function (e, t, n) {
            function a() {
                var e = t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
                    n = t.createElement("script");
                n.type = "text/javascript", n.async = !0, n.src = "https://beacon-v2.helpscout.net", e.parentNode.insertBefore(n, e);
            }

            if (e.Beacon = n = function (t, n, a) {
                e.Beacon.readyQueue.push({ method: t, options: n, data: a });
            }, n.readyQueue = [], "complete" === t.readyState) return a();
            e.attachEvent ? e.attachEvent("onload", a) : e.addEventListener("load", a, !1);
        }(window, document, window.Beacon || function () { });
        window.Beacon('config', {
        color: '#9747FF' 
      });
        window.Beacon('init', '75d9824d-49ff-4f02-9789-2a04a2f2b0f9');
  `;
    document.head.appendChild(this.beaconScript);
  }
```

i was added scprit like that i think it is usefull for it

Comment: this.beaconScript.text ? what should put into this ?

Comment: your script js code

Comment: you are add path like this instead of text

this.beaconScript.src = 'path/to/your/script.js';